# Nginx forward based on a response from another service

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx setup for reverse proxying into my backend servers. I have a requirement where I need to send the traffic to an IP if it is retrieved from another HTTP request successfully otherwise send it to another IP. 
Such as I have an incoming request with request_param=abcd(it could be any value). If I am able to retrieve abcd from http://service/abcd, then route it to IP1, else route it to IP2.

Something like below :

```
server {
     location /${abcd} {
     if(http://service/$abcd returns HTTP 200)
          then proxy_pass http://$http_host_1$request_uri;
     else
         proxy_pass http://$http_host_2$request_uri;
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openresty is the solution for this - which is built on top of nginx and lets us configure lua code for intercepting nginx request handling and put our custom code.
https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/

I used the rewrite_by_lua  in the access phase to redirect request based on conditions.
[image]
Also needed to use a library lua-resty-http to make the external request.

`cd /usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty
curl -O  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http/v0.15/lib/resty/http.lua
curl -O  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http/v0.15/lib/resty/http_headers.lua`

```
server {
    listen 443;

    location /location {
        lua_need_request_body on;
        set $backendurl 'http_host_1/request_uri';

        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
            local abcd = ""

            if (body) then
                abcd = string.match(body, "my_pattern")

                if (abcd ~= nil and abcd ~= '') then
                   local http = require "resty.http"
                   local httpc = http.new()
                   local external_url = "http://service/" .. abcd
                   local res, err = httpc:request_uri(external_url, {
                            method = "GET",
                            headers = {
                            ["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                            }
                        })

                        local response_status = res.status

                        if response_status == 404 then
                            ngx.var.backendurl = "http_host_2"
                        end
                 end
            end
        }

        proxy_pass http://$backendurl/$uri;
    }
}
```